# Список ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Необходимо сделать список из семи дней недели. Я Id уже дал и нашёл.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Поясните, что у вас не получается.

Comment: Вы выбрали сложный путь изучения разработки для начинающего - выспрашивать каждое элементарное действие. Ответов можно ждать днями и так и не получить их. Разработчикам не очень нравятся такие фразы "я не умею массив делать" и отвечать на них они не торопятся. Рекомендую не мучаться и прочитать для начала пару книжек: Б.Эккеля по Java (как делать массив) и Б.Харди по Android (как сделать список), а вопросы задавать по действительным проблемам, а не элементарным действиям, которые отлично расписаны в сотнях источников.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прежде всего изучите, как строятся [ListView в Android](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/82-urok42-spisok-listview.html).
Для динамического добавления дней недели, рекомендую создать массив и написать адаптер к нему, чтобы адаптер читал массив и передавал данные в ListView (об этом так же написано в статье по ссылке). Если Вы изучаете Android с нуля, рекомендую этот ресурс в постоянное пользование.

Answer (score 0):

Делайте массив из 7 дней, адаптер к Listview и вперед

Comment: Адапатер, это как датасет. В него данные, а компонент отображает из него

Comment: Все зделал, спасибо вам огромное.

Comment: А как задать вопрос?

Comment: Напишите решение проблемы более детально, чтобы пользователям было легче понять ваш ответ.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/146778)